# Ayuda con condición en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Saludos amigos de la comunidad tengo una duda como puedo crear una condición que los usuarios que tengan el estado **¡por asistir!** no se puedan registrarse en la inscripción de un proyecto, ya que es un requisito que el usuario haya asistido a la charla para poder ser inscrito a un proyecto. Les explico el sistema funciona de esta manera los usuarios hacen una pre- inscripción en el sistema para almacenar esos datos tengo dos tablas las cuales son:

`Tabla Usuarios
Id, usuario, clave, fk_nivel, correo, cedula, nombres, apellidos`

`Tabla pre_inscripcion
Fk_cedula, fk_idcarrera, estado`

Luego de eso tengo las siguientes tablas para hacer el registro de los proyectos y saber que alumnos están inscriptos en ese proyecto

`Tabla: inscripción_proyectos
Id, titulo_proyecto, fk_departamento, fk_profesor, fk_cedula`

`Tabla: inscripción_alumnos
Id, fk_inscripción_proyectos, fk_cedula`

Ahora mi duda es como puede hacer esa condición…

código que uso para insertar en inscripción_alumnos:

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['guardar'])){

$id=$_POST['id'];
$idinscripcion_proyectos=$_POST['idinscripcion_proyectos'];
$cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
$nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];

  $sql="SELECT * FROM inscripcion_alumnos WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
  $res=mysql_query($sql,$link);
  $nrows=mysql_num_rows($res);

if($nrows==0){

for ($i = 0; $i < count($idinscripcion_proyectos); $i++) {
    foreach ($nombres as $key => $nombre) {

 if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO inscripcion_alumnos (id,idinscripcion_proyectos,cedula,nombres,apellidos) VALUES 
    ('$id','$last_id','$cedula[$key]','$nombres[$key]','$apellidos[$key]')",$link));

}
}

echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel teal lighten-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !
</h5>
</div>";
header("refresh:5;registrar_inscripcion.php");

          }
  else 

echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
<h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
¡ Ups Aviso: Disculpe Este Usuario no Puede Inscribirse en proyecto ya que no asistio a la charla ! 
</h5>
</div>";
header("refresh:5;registrar_inscripcion.php");

}

?>
```

ahora lo he editado asi pero de igual manera me brincan los mjs de alertas:

```
    <?php
 if (isset ($_POST['guardar'])){


$id=$_POST['id'];
$idinscripcion_proyectos=$_POST['idinscripcion_proyectos'];
$cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
$nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];



   $sql_user="SELECT count(1) as item FROM pre_inscripcion WHERE estado IN('NO Asistio', 'Por Asistir') AND cedula='$cedula[$key]' LIMIT 1";
   $res=mysql_query($sql_user,$link);
   if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

    echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
    <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
    ¡ Ups Aviso: Disculpe Este Usuario no Puede Inscribirse en proyecto ya que no Asistio a la Charla ! 
    </h5>
    </div>";
    //header("refresh:5;registrar_inscripcion.php");

    }


  $sql="SELECT * FROM inscripcion_alumnos WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
  $res=mysql_query($sql,$link);
  $nrows=mysql_num_rows($res);

    //******** He editado esta parte (A. Cedano)
if($nrows==0)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($idinscripcion_proyectos); $i++) 
    {
        foreach ($nombres as $key => $nombre) 
        {

            if (mysql_query("INSERT INTO inscripcion_alumnos (id,idinscripcion_proyectos,cedula,nombres,apellidos) VALUES 
                ('$id','$last_id','$cedula[$key]','$nombres[$key]','$apellidos[$key]')",$link))
            {


                echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel teal lighten-2 center'>
                    <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
                    ¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !
                    </h5>
                    </div>";
                //header("refresh:5;registrar_inscripcion.php");
            }
            else 
            {


                echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
                <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
                ¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado ! 
                </h5>
                </div>";
                //header("refresh:5;registrar_inscripcion.php");
            }
        }
    }
}       



?>
```

Comment: Te sugiero cambiar a MYSQLI, las consultas con mysql fueron deshabilitadas en 2013, porque no son tan seguras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plantearé la solución a tu problema en dos etapas. Primero la posibilidad de verificar la asistencia (a), segundo el manejo de los datos (b).

## A. Verificar la asistencia

Para ello podrías sencillamente tener una **tabla auxiliar** en la base de datos en la que sólo estén inscritos los alumnos que hayan asistido. Esta tabla podría incluso servir como control de asistencia, por ejemplo en ella podrías registrar las fechas en que un alumno ha asistido a un curso o taller determinado y otras cosas...

Para verificar si el alumno asistió sólo haces una consulta a dicha tabla buscando el id del estudiante, si se encuentra el id significa que asistió, si no lo encuentra, significa que no ha asistido.

## B. Consultar a la Base de Datos

> Esto es lo más importante. Se requiere siempre un buen manejo de nuestros datos y que el mismo sea hecho de forma eficaz.

No te asustes con la solución que te voy a dar, puede parecer larga, pero si haces algo así te vas a ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza en el futuro.

Lo primero que quiero indicarte es que tu **código es inseguro**, ya que no estás usando PDO ni MySQLi, sino extensiones obsoletas e inseguras de PHP tales como `mysql_query()` y `mysql_num_rows()`, al respecto de las cuales [dice el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php):

> Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP
>   7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL. Véase también la guía MySQL: elegir una API y sus P+F
>   relacionadas para más información. Alternatives to this function
>   include: mysqli_query() and PDO::query()

Estas extensiones son susceptibles de [Inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php).

### Solución propuesta con PDO

Propongo una solución basada en PDO. Yo lo prefiero con respecto a MySQLi, aunque cualquiera de los dos es válido.

Lo ideal es tener una clase en tu PHP que se dedique a hacer la conexión, de forma que **no tengas que andar preocupándote por eso cada vez que tengas que conectar**. Sólo invocas a tu clase, llamada `Conexion` en este caso. Además la clase `Conexion` **tendrá varios métodos o funciones que te facilitarán la vida y lo mejor de todo es que puedes agregar en ella cuantos métodos necesites**. Eso sí, cuando crees un método permite que éste tenga un uso múltiple, o sea, las cosas particulares pásalas en parámetro, sea al mismo método, sea a otro de la clase.

También, este modelo de Clase podría ser útil en cualquier proyecto PHP que tengas.

Bueno, esta sería la clase `Conexion`que podría ser un archivo php llamado `conexion.php` el cual deberás incluir cada vez que necesites usar la clase.

**conexion.php**

```
<?php
    class Conexion {
        /*
         * Rellenar estos campos con tus datos *
         */

        private $host      = 'localhost';
        private $user      = '';
        private $dbname    = '';
        private $pass      = '';
        private $error;

        public function __construct(){
            // Set DSN
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname.';charset=utf8';

            // Set options
            $options = array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
                );

        // Create a new PDO instance
            try{
                $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
                }
                // Catch any errors
            catch(PDOException $e){
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            }
        }


        public static function getInstance()
        {
            if (self::$instance == null) {
                $className = __CLASS__;
                self::$instance = new $className();
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }


        public function query($query){
            $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
        }

        public function execute(){
            return $this->stmt->execute();
        }

        public function resultset(){
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        public function lastInsertId(){
            return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
        }

        public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
            if (is_null($type)) {
                switch (true) {
                    case is_int($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                        break;
                    case is_bool($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                        break;
                    case is_null($value):
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                        break;
                    default:
                        $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
            }
            $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
        }

        public function single(){
            $this->execute();
            return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        public function valor(){
            $this->execute();
            $valor=$this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
            return (empty($valor)) ? 0 : $valor;
        }

        public function si_existe(){
            $this->execute();
            if ($this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }


}

?>
```

### ¿Cómo uso la clase `Conexion`?

Ahora viene lo bueno. En el caso del problema planteado en tu pregunta, y en cualquier otro caso que tenga que ver con bases de datos.

**tuarchivo.php**

```
include_once "conexion.php"; // esto incluirá la clase Conexion en el archivo actual

//Datos obtenidos del formulario

$id=$_POST['id'];
$idinscripcion_proyectos=$_POST['idinscripcion_proyectos'];
$cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
$nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];

/*
 *Aquí creas una nueva instancia de la clase 
 * e invocas al método que devuelve una conexión válida
 */

    $cnx = new Conexion();
    $db=$cnx->getInstance();

/*
 *Ya tendrás en la variable $db una conexión disponible a tu BD 
 * Ahora envías las consultas a tu objeto de BD
 */

/*
 * Verificar que el usuario existe en la tabla de asistencias
 * Enviaremos una consulta preparada a la BD
 * Una consulta preparada protege a la BD de Inyección SQL
 * Siempre es recomendable separar la consulta y los datos
 * Por eso verás que en la consulta aparece `WHERE id=:id`
 * porque luego `id`es pasado en parámetro usando `bind`
 * El método `si_existe` nos dirá si hay alguien o no con ese id
 * devolviendo `true` o `false`según el caso 
 */
    $consulta= "SELECT id_alumno FROM tabla_de_asistencias WHERE id_alumno=:id LIMIT 1";
    $db->query($consulta);
    $db->bind(':id', $id);
    $datos=$db->si_existe();

/*
 * Ahora verificamos si $datos es `true` 
 * Si lo es significa que el alumno con ese id ha asistido 
 * y que en consecuencia podemos insertar
 * El `INSERT`se hace también mediante consulta preparada
 * enviando los datos separados de la cadena SQL `INSERT` 
 */
if ($datos)
{
    $consulta="INSERT INTO inscripcion_alumnos  
               (id,idinscripcion_proyectos,cedula,nombres,apellidos) 
               VALUES (:id, :idinscripcion, :cedula, :nombres, :apellidos)";
    $db->query($consulta);
    $db->bind(':id', $id);
    $db->bind(':idinscripcion', $last_id);
    $db->bind(':cedula',$cedula[$key]);
    $db->bind(':nombres',$nombres[$key]);
    $db->bind(':apellidos',$apellidos[$key]);
    $db->execute();
}
else
{
    echo "Este usuario no está inscrito en la tabla de asistencias";
}
```

Espero te sirva.

Si tienes dudas, las puedes plantear en comentario.

Comment: gracias amigo por tu comentario, te explico actualmente uso PDO el problema es que es un sistema que esta listo y solo falta poner esa condicion nada mas para terminar el sistema el unico problema es ese hacer esa condicion que cuando un usuario o varios usuarios tengan ese estado no puedan inscribirse y el sistema emita un msj diciendo Disculpe Este(os) Usuarios no Puede Inscribirse en proyecto ya que no Asistieron  a la Charla

Comment: @yoclens La mecánica sería como se muestra en el ejemplo: Teniendo una posible tabla llamada por ej. `asistencias` en las que tengas los usuarios que han asistido, buscas en ese tabla si el id existe. Si existe haces el `INSERT` en la tabla `inscripcion` y si no existe muestras el mensaje de que no está inscrito.  Puedes hacer una prueba con el ejemplo que te pongo, no es tan difícil, la clase de Conexión puedes usarla tal cual y usas el código para evaluar las condiciones.

Comment: esa tabla ya existe que es la tabla de pre-inscripcion en la cual los campos son los siguiente: Tabla pre_inscripcion
Fk_cedula, fk_idcarrera, estado

Comment: @yocles Ya, imagino que la columna `cedula`de la tabla `pre_inscripcion`es la que hace referencia al alumno. Entonces haciendo `"SELECT cedula FROM pre_inscripcion WHERE cedula=$cedula"`podrás verificar si está inscrito y a partir de ahí insertar o mostrar que no está inscrito.

Comment: si amigo pero, viste el ejemplo que puse de ultimo de como lo hice pero me brincan los mjs de alerta arriba esta

Comment: @yoclens Es que esto lo que hace es liarte más: `$sql_user="SELECT count(1) as item FROM pre_inscripcion WHERE estado IN('NO Asistio', 'Por Asistir') AND cedula='$cedula[$key]' LIMIT 1";` **Eso no es necesario** Si en la tabla `pre_inscripcion` están los usuarios que han asistido tan sólo tienes que verificar que la `cedula` del usuario (la cédula o la clave foránea, la columna de la tabla pre_inscripcion que apunta al usuario) está en dicha tabla, si lo está significa que asistió, si no lo está significa que no asistió... no entiendo por qué liarse con eso de `WHERE IN (estado...`

Comment: es que en la tabla de pre-inscripcion puede haber tres estados a la vez que seria Por Asistir, Asistio y No Asistio por eso lo hice asi

Comment: @yoclens Me he permitido de editar la última parte de tu código, ya que, al tener las llaves de apertura y cierre disparatadas faltaban llaves o sobraban. Revísalo no sea que se me haya escapado alguna llave y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: me da error en el else

Comment: @yoclens Uf sí había una llave mal puesta. He editado de nuevo, prueba.

Comment: faltaba otra llave al final pero kigual da error: Notice: Undefined variable: key in C:\xampp\htdocs\scomunitario\admin\registrar_inscripcion.php on line 116

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\scomunitario\admin\registrar_inscripcion.php on line 116    hace referencia a est linea: $sql_user="SELECT count(1) as item FROM pre_inscripcion WHERE estado IN('NO Asistio', 'Por Asistir') AND cedula='$cedula[$key]' LIMIT 1";

Comment: Los dos bucles for que tienen son confusos: `for ($i = 0; $i < count($idinscripcion_proyectos); $i++)     {` y luego `foreach ($nombres as $key => $nombre)  {` ¿lo que almacenas aquí es un arreglo (array)?: `$nombres=$_POST['nombres'];` Y ¿esta variable es otro array: `$idinscripcion_proyectos` ?

Comment: ok te entiendo pero ellos funcionan bien, bueno esto si se me a puesto difícil

Comment: No. Creo que el error se refiere a esto: `$nombres as $key` del 2º bucle for. ¿No estarás tratando cadenas simples como arreglos? Si `$nombre`
 es un solo nombre el bucle for sobra, y si `$idinscripcion_proyectos` es un solo id, también sobre ese bucle for.

Comment: observa estas tres imágenes  [http://prntscr.com/ekivb0]  [http://prntscr.com/ekivd4]   [http://prntscr.com/ekivek]

Comment: @yoclens Ayer se me hizo tarde. ¿Pudiste finalmente resolver tu problema?

Comment: nah amigo ya no se que hacer  
perdona tanta molestia y el abuso [mega.nz/#!dpw1mJCQ!qQrcIPdr0K4XecyXmFiwM1MjKFUy3m_YA1Vv9Ukz‌​fQk] mira el codigo toy que lloro

Comment: [https://mega.nz/#!dpw1mJCQ!qQrcIPdr0K4XecyXmFiwM1MjKFUy3m_YA1Vv9UkzfQk] no amigo nada

Answer (score 0):

Yo crearia una tabla **charla_proyecto** que tuviera por columna :

```
id, fk_inscripción_proyectos, fk_usuario
```

Asi siempre voy a poder estar controlando que usuario presenciaron la charla de x proyecto

Comment: no es que tienen que presenciar la charla de un proyecto es que tienen que asistir a la charla para que el administrador u secretaria puedan cambiarle el estado de por asisitir a asistio, el problema es cuando vy hacer el registro del proyecto que si un usuario tiene esa condición no puede inscribirse

Comment: haber creo que no entendiste lo que te quiero decir. Cuando vayas a inscribir a un usuario en un proyecto lo que tienes que hacer es verificar en la tabla que yo crearía "charla_proyecto" si ese usuario asistió a esa charla de ese proyecto debería de aparecer en la tabla sino significa que no asistio.

Comment: ok, ya te entendí pero ahora es como debería hacer esa condición a la hora de hacer la insersion

Comment: Haber supongo que puedes tener un usuario sin haber asistido a ninguna charla, en ese caso creas el usuario normalmente y para indicar que ese usuario participo en 'x' charla de 'y' proyecto, tendrías que hacer un formulario que recogiera esa información( proyecto,  usuario)  y la guardas en la tabla charla_proyecto, y la verificación seria como te lo explique en el comentario anterior

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo en el momento de crear tu tabla le agregas un **check**

```
CHECK ((estado='estadoAceptado1')  
       OR (estado='estadoAceptado2'))
```

Puedes probar `CHECK (estado!='porAsistir')`  pero no estoy seguro de esta forma

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55520/discussion-on-answer-by-carlos-ayuda-con-condicion-en-php).

Answer (score 0):

Yo pienso que sencillamente creas otra tabla que llamadas Asistencias o como dice @OmarMiranda "charla_proyecto", la cual tenga algo asi:

**Asistencias**

```
ID --- DESC

1  --- Asistio

2  --- Por Asistir
```

Y en el formulario de la **preinscripcion** colocas un **SELECT** con esta tabla de Asistencias.

El mostrara los dos posibles estados: Asistio - No asistio

luego al **inscribir** puedes verificar con una sentencia asi:

```
$id=$_POST["id_del_estudiante"];

SELECT * FROM estudiantes WHERE asistio_ID = 1 AND id_estudiante = $id
```

Si existen ambos que te diga "El estudiante puede inscribir".

Si no existe y no devuelve el resultado, te diga "este estudiante no puede ser inscrito" y borre los campos

Esto lo harias con **mysql_rows**

Si te parece bien asi puedo ayudarte a armar el SELECT y el formulario.

Codigo:

```
<?php 
include 'conexion.php';
function opciones(){

global $conexion;
    $sql="SELECT * FROM asistencias";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($sql);
    while ($datos = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
    {
     echo "<option value='".$datos['ID']."'>".$datos['DESC']."</option>";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="preinscribir.php">
    <h1>
Sistema para preinscribir
    </h1>
    Ingrese id<input type="text" name="id">
    Ingrese nombre<input type="text" name="nombre">
    Seleccione la asistencia a la charla
    <select>
    <?php opciones();?>
    </select>
    <input type"submit" name="pre" value="Preinscribir">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias @Victor por tu respuesta te explico automáticamente cuando el usuario se registra que seria su pre-inscripcion su estado es Por Asistir, después dependiendo si el usuario(alumno) haya asistido a la charla o no haya asistido el administrador cambia su estado a No Asistio o Asistio. editare la pregunta para que veas como lo tengo ahora pero de igual manera me brincan los mjs de alerta no se si sera porque lo tengo mal estructurado

Comment: esta bien :) te ayudare

Comment: si colocas el error tambien seria de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_user="SELECT count(1) as item FROM pre_inscripcion WHERE estado IN('NO Asistio', 'Por Asistir') AND cedula='$cedula[$key]' LIMIT 1";
   $res=mysql_query($sql_user,$link);
   if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {

    echo "<div class='col s12 card-panel blue lighten-2 center'>
    <h5 class='black-text text-darken-2 center CONDENSED LIGHT5'>
    ¡ Ups Aviso: Disculpe Este Usuario no Puede Inscribirse en proyecto ya que no Asistio a la Charla ! 
    </h5>
    </div>";
    //header("refresh:5;registrar_inscripcion.php");

    }
```

Esta porción de código siempre va a entrar en el if, y por ende no va a realizar el else, que es donde está tu método de inserción. Porque preguntas por la cantidad de filas devueltas que siempre va a ser mayor a cero, por más que tu cantidad contada es cero, me explico? Tienes que preguntar por el valor devuelto del **COUNT()**